# Updating elements in a Map which has immutable objects

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Java Map which is deserialized into immutable objects from a json similar to below and has multiple levels of nesting. I have a second Map containing alternate values for some of the strings. The second map has the value appended to the key for the nested levels to differentiate between different elements in an array. I would like to replace the values in the first map using the values found in the second map. Are there any suggestions for the approach that could used to solve the below?

```
{
  "product": "Internet",
  "version": 3.1,
  "releaseDate": "2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "person": {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "phones": {
      "home": "800-123-4567",
      "mobile": "877-123-1234"
    },
    "email": [
      "jd@example.com",
      "jd@example.org"
    ],
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "registered": true,
    "emergencyContacts": [
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phone": "888-555-1212",
        "relationship": "spouse"
      },
      {
        "name": "Justin Doe",
        "phone": "877-123-1212",
        "relationship": "parent"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Map containing alternate values

```
    {
      "product": "Strong Internet",
      "person.name=John Doe" : "Barry Richards",
      "person.emergencyContacts.name=Jane Doe" : "Jane Richards"
    }
```

Resulting Map

```
    {
      "product": "Strong Internet",
      "version": 3.1,
      "releaseDate": "2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "person": {
        "id": 12345,
        "name": "Barry Richards",
        "phones": {
          "home": "800-123-4567",
          "mobile": "877-123-1234"
        },
        "email": [
          "jd@example.com",
          "jd@example.org"
        ],
        "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "registered": true,
        "emergencyContacts": [
          {
            "name": "Jane Richards",
            "phone": "888-555-1212",
            "relationship": "spouse"
          },
          {
            "name": "Justin Doe",
            "phone": "877-123-1212",
            "relationship": "parent"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Flatten json's, merge and unflatten. Map object by object, compare values, pick wanted one. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thank you! I have created an immutable map from the json. However I am still figuring out how to compare element by element and replace values especially since all the objects in my map are immutable.